# Eclipse - Java Array ID Values are Equal. Cannot change values independently

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

I have two arrays that I create like this:

```
public int GameBoard[][] = new int[30][14];
public int DirectionMap[][] = new int[30][14];
```

I then initialize the arrays like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < GameBoard[i].length; j++)
    {
        GameBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

... //Same for DirectionMap
```

When I run the function:

```
DirectionMap = AStar(GameBoard);
```

To render the pathfinding map that my units will follow, DirectionMap is correctly set to the values generated based on my GameBoard.  However GameBoard is set to the result as well.  When I run the application in Debug Mode within Eclipse, I can see that the ID's of the two arrays are the same.  For some reason they seem to be pointing to the memory space.  My AStar function does not modify the GameBoard array at all.   The only reference to it is int retVal[][] = GameBoard;

My function prototype is public int[][] AStar(int[][] Board); and it returns the int[][] retVal.

I have no idea why I cannot change the values of DirectionMap without GameBoard following.  I have never had any issues like this before.

Any ideas are really appreciated.  Thanks for your help.

```
        public int[][] AStar(int[][] Board)
        {
        int retVal[][] = Board;

        //Initialize All Needed Lists
        int width = retVal.length;
        int height = retVal[0].length;
        int goalX = 0;
        int goalY = 0;
        //List<Node> fieldInfo = new ArrayList<Node>(); 

        Node fieldArray[][] = new Node[width][height];

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                fieldArray[i][j] = new Node(i, j);
                if (retVal[i][j] == 2)
                {
                    fieldArray[i][j].setOpen(1);
                    fieldArray[i][j].setDirection(10); //Set as target
                    goalX = i;
                    goalY = j;
                }
                if (retVal[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    fieldArray[i][j].setOpen(0);
                    fieldArray[i][j].setDirection(9); //Set as wall
                }
            }
        }

                    //Add AStar Algorithm Here

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (fieldArray[i][j].getDirection() == 0)
                {
                    //Occurs when node was never reached
                    int dX = i - goalX;
                    int dY = j - goalY;
                    if (dX < 0)
                        dX = -dX;
                    if (dY < 0)
                        dY = -dY;
                    if (dY > dX)
                        fieldArray[i][j].setDirection(1);
                    else
                    {
                        if (i > goalX)
                            fieldArray[i][j].setDirection(7);
                        if (i < goalX)
                            fieldArray[i][j].setDirection(3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                retVal[i][j] = fieldArray[i][j].getDirection();
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the AStar(int[][]) method code?

Comment: I've edited the initial posting.

Comment: `int retVal[][] = Board;` then later `retVal[i][j] = fieldArray[i][j].getDirection();`. That'll do it.

Comment: Should I be using int retVal[][] = new int[val1][val2];  ----   retVal = Board;   --- Can I set them equal, or must I run through every value?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: You answered first.  If you post something like what you said below, I'll accept is at the solution.

Comment: @Nathan: I had to run an urgent errand so didn't have time for a full answer but thought I'd post a quick comment. tsatiz has pretty much covered it - as I expect you've realised now that you are simply copying a reference when using `int retVal[][] = Board;` rather than making a new copy. As tsatiz mentions, doing a full value copy would work although I'd personally just clone `Board` using `int retVal[][] = Board.clone();` - I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember when you are passing an object to methods you are actually passing a copy of reference. So when you initialise `retVal[][] = Board;` you actually point `Board` using another reference `retVal`. And you are returning the same reference to `DirectionMap`. Hence same id's for `Board` and `DirectionMap`. Consider [array copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that the ID's of the two arrays are the same. For some
>   reason they seem to be pointing to the memory space

The `int[]` array in Java has 0's as default values.

```
int[] x = new int[2];
System.out.println(x[0]); // prints 0
System.out.println(x[1]); // prints 0
```

Comment: That only means that I don't have to initialize anything.  That doesn't change the issue with the arrays pointing to the same values.

Comment: @NathanTornquist They are not pointing to the same array. At least, in the code you provided.

Comment: They shouldn't be.  When the code starts, the arrays are independent.  After AStar() is executed though, the ID values match.  AStar() is run after I touch the screen.  There is no reason that they should match.

Comment: @NathanTornquist Then, you need to show us the `AStar()` method details.

Comment: I've added the AStar() method above.

Answer (score 0):

> The only reference to it is int retVal[][] = GameBoard;

Java arrays are objects. If at any point you are setting array = array, you are setting one reference to point to the same object as the other.