# Both variables changing when I modify one

Tags: java, variables, matrix

I'm doing an algorithm in like this:

```
public int[][] moveLeft(int m[][], int[] index){
    Puzzle x = new Puzzle(m);
    System.out.println(x);
    int[][] p = m;
    int temp = p[index[0]][index[1]];
    p[index[0]][index[1]] = p[index[0]][index[1]-1];
    p[index[0]][index[1]-1] = temp;
    return p;
}
```

To be more specific, what i'm trying to do is to change the position of certain values and return the new matrix, but when i'm debuging, i noted that the value "m" also changues, even when im doing changes to the value p. What is wrong here?

Comment: can you not debug and look at where/when m changes

Comment: what is Puzzle x = new Puzzle(m); doing?

Comment: Ok first of all, puzzle its just an object holding a matrix, done that for testing purposes, the moment when m starts "imitating" p happens at line 6, when i switch the positions in "p", the debugger shows that m switches positions too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your culprit:

```
int[][] p = m;
```

Once you do this, `p` and `m` refer to the same exact object, because arrays in Java are reference objects. Any change to `p`'s content will be reflected in `m`, because `p` and `m` are two different names for a single object.

If you need `p` to be a copy of `m`, you should do it explicitly. Here is [a link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686523/335858) showing you how it is done.

Comment: Thats the problem! Thanks a lot man...
How can I "copy" the object?

Comment: @chntgomez Take a look at the answer that I linked, it shows you two ways of doing it (through cloning and through arraycopy).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
int [][] p = new int[m.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
   p[i] = m[i].clone();
```

instead of **int[][] p = m;**

so that `p` and `m` refer to **two different objects**.

Comment: Nailed it with your solution. Thanks a lot!