# Java - how to return in a method multidimensional array without aliasing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, return

I'm aware that arrays are objects and in java objects are transfered by reference which could cause aliasing so objects should be returned with in this form to not cause aliasing:

return **new** (object(parameters));

So this is what I'm trying to do with multidimensional arrays, however for some reason compiler says I have an error : "array dimension missing".

```
public int[][] Testing(int[][]arr)
    {
        int[][]newArr=new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
            {
                newArr[i][j]=arr[i][arr[0].length-1-j];
            }
            return new int[][]newArr;  
        }      
    }
```

Could anyone tell me how to return in a method an multidimensional array without aliasing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating your array inside your method, there is no risk for aliasing in this scenario. Noone else can get a reference to your array.

A simple

```
return newArr;
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

`return newArr;` is the one you should use. Change your code as follows

```
  public int[][] Testing(int[][]arr){
    int[][]newArr=new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            newArr[i][j]=arr[i][arr[0].length-1-j];
        }

    }
    return newArr; // rerunning the array witch created inside this method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return a copy of `newArr`?
see the following:
[copy a 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java)

If you don't need a copy - just return `newArr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `newArr` as:

```
return newArr;
```

Because it tells the compiler that it is an `int` but was declared as a 2D array.

Comment: i am so sorry ..... yea u can use a simple "return newArr; " since you have a 2d arr method/function.

Comment: This solution already posted and it duplicates existing one. Please post only if you have any value ad Or an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class First {
    int a[][]=new int[3][3];
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] Arr()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < a.length;j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return(a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First f = new First();
        int c[][]=new int[3][3];
        c=f.Arr();
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(c[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> you should return newArr instead of int[][]newArr.

```
public int[][] Testing(int[][]arr)
{
    int[][]newArr=new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            newArr[i][j]=arr[i][arr[0].length-1-j];
        }
        return new newArr;  
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[][] Testing(int[][] arr){
    int[][] newArr = new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++){       
            newArr[i][j] = arr[i][arr[0].length-1-j];
        }            
    }    
    return newArr; 
}
```

Note: If you directly print the newArr in your main method you will get an error [[Ljava.lang.String;@

To avoid this use for loop to print your array output