# Return 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a method which creates a 2D array. I want to return this 2D array to use it in another class.

```
public class drawBoxClass {
public String[] drawBox(int boxLength) {

    String[][] arrayBox = new String[boxLength][boxLength+1];

    //method stuff

    return new String[][]arrayBox;
    }
}
```

I've tried googling on how to return 2D string arrays, but I don't get how to return it.

I'm getting "array dimension missing".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - how to return in a method multidimensional array without aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519100/java-how-to-return-in-a-method-multidimensional-array-without-aliasing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

(1) Return type of `drawBox` method signature should be 2d array i.e., `String[][]`, your current method signature can only return single dimensional array

(2) `return` statement should be like `return arrayBox` (no need to specify the variable type again)

```
public String[][] drawBox(int boxLength) {
    String[][] arrayBox = new String[boxLength][boxLength+1];
    //method stuff
    return arrayBox;
}
```