# I am confused on copying 2D arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was reading this post on Stack overflow: [copy a 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java)   and I am a little confused on how the clone method works here...

```
public int[][] CopyMap(int[][] Map)
{
    int [][] copy = new int[Map.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < Map.length; i++)
        copy[i] = Map[i].clone();
    return copy; 
}
```

I know how to copy using enhanced for loops but I would like to fully understand this way.

1) Why do we put the Map.length in the first set of square brackets but not Map[0].length in the second set of square brackets for `int[][] copy = new int[Map.length][];`?  Don't we have to initialize the length of the columns as well? I'm guessing that we can't clone a 2D array but we can clone a row or column at a time.

2) By cloning the columns one column at a time and putting it into our 2D array it sets the length of the columns for us?

3) Could we reverse this code by doing this

```
public int[][] CopyMap(int[][] Map)
{
    int [][] copy = new int[][Map[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < Map[0].length; i++)
        copy[i] = Map[i].clone();
    return copy; 
}
```

4) Also `copy[i]` ? This is a 2D array, so shouldn't it be `copy[i][]` ? Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In Java a 2D array is essentially an array of arrays (possibly with different lengths). It is important to remember this. For example, this is OK:

```
 int[][] ar = new int[2][];
 ar[0] = new int[8]; // ar[0][0..7]
 ar[1] = new int[4]; // ar[1][0..3]
```

The syntax `new int[8][10]` can be used as a convenience to create 8 separate arrays of 10 elements each.

If you are familiar with C: an `int[][]` in Java is more similar to an `int**` in C.

Note: `Map` is a terrible name for a variable in Java; variable names generally start with lowercase letters and there is also a very common base container interface of the same name.

> 1) Why do we put the Map.length in the first set of square brackets but not Map[0].length in the second set of square brackets for int [][] copy = new int[Map.length][]; ?

Because we are starting with an array of *Map.length* `int[]`'s, and then cloning those `int[]`s one at a time.

> Don't we have to initialize the length of the columns as well?

No, because when we go through each `int[]` in `Map`, we just use `clone()` to copy it: `copy[i] = Map[i].clone()`.

> By cloning the columns one column at a time and putting it into our 2D array it sets the length of the columns for us?

A "column" is just a concept you made up that is only relevant to tabular data (column-major tabular data in your specific context). Anyways, "setting the length" isn't exactly accurate because it implied that something whose length is being set existed in the first place; but when you do `int x[][] = new x[5][]`, `x[0]` is `null` until you assign it to something. By cloning the `int[]`s one at a time, we're just... cloning them one at a time. So, yes, each clone will be the same size as the original.

> 3) Could we reverse this code by doing this
>
> ```
> public int[][] CopyMap(int[][] Map)
> {
>    int [][] copy = new int[][Map[0].length];
>    for(int i = 0; i < Map[0].length; i++)
>        copy[i] = Map[i].clone();
>    return copy;
> }
> ```

No; and hopefully the reason why is clear now that you know that an `int[][]` is an array of arrays. The expression `new int[][size]` doesn't make much sense; it says that we want each `int[]` in the array to have a given size, but it doesn't say how many `int[]`s are in the array. It's wrong for the same reason that `int[] x = new int[]` is wrong.

> 4) Also `copy[i]` ? This is a 2D array, so shouldn't it be `copy[i][]` ? Or something like that.

No, it should be `copy[i]`. I'll leave figuring out the reasons as an exercise.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm which explains it well.