# Changes made to a local variable is linked to a node?

Tags: java, a-star

I have the following codes for building a node:

```
public class Node {
    int state[][];
    String totalPath;
    int gn;
    int hn;
    int fn;
    boolean isLeaf;
    Node parentNode;
    int zeroX;
    int zeroY;
}
```

assume that I have constructed a node:
    `Node currentNode = new Node();`

but when I do this:

```
int subState[][] = currentNode.state;
switcher = subState[ycheck-1][xcheck];
subState[ycheck-1][xcheck] = 0;
subState[ycheck][xcheck] = switcher;
```

why is it that when i print substate[][] and currentNode.state[][], it appears that both 2D arrays are the same? isn't it supposed to work like this: substate[][] changes but currentNode.state[][] stays the same? why is it that every change i do to substate[][], the same is done to currentNode.state? is there a workaround for this?

thanks to those who will answer!

Comment: because subState[][] and currentNode.state are the same integer matrix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this in java `arrFoo = new array; arrBar = arrFoo` what happens is that both `arrFoo` and `arrBar` look at the same memory reference. This will mean that any changes done to one array will be implicitly done to the other.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java) previous SO post for more information.

Comment: @JennyMelody: I have updated my answer to point to another answer with a more robust solution. I would recommend that over my previous recommendation.

Comment: int subState[][] = new int [3][];
subState[0] = currentNode.state[0].clone();
subState[1] = currentNode.state[1].clone();
subState[2] = currentNode.state[2].clone();... this ALSO WORKS!!! :D thanks!!!

Comment: @JennyMelody: Please take a look at the most upvoted answer in the question I linked to in my answer. That should help you sovle the problem you are after.

Comment: @JennyMelody: Glad it worked for you. That being said, I would still recommend the approach in the linked question. `Clone` can be a bit messy sometimes ;).

Comment: basically, .clone() only "clones" a 1D array, so we have to copy the rows one by one!!! thanks for the help @npinti :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

> it appears that both 2D arrays are the same

Because there are not two of them, **there's only one of them**. This line:

```
int subState[][] = currentNode.state;
```

...gives you a *reference* to the `currentNode.state` array, not a *copy* of it. Exactly the way that this code:

```
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> m2 = m1;
m1.put("one", "uno");
System.out.println(m2.get("one"));
```

...shows "uno", because `m1` and `m2` refer to the **same** map object.

Since you're changing the state of the object (array), you see that change regardless of which reference you look at the object through.