# Same object, different outcome

Tags: java, queue

So I have this generic object `State` which apparently changes its value despite not being edited. Here is what I mean - by invoking the same element in the `Queue` I am getting different outcomes.

```
System.out.println(mapString(que.element().getMapState()));
System.out.println(que.element());
```

The outcome:

[image: the outcome]

**The second outcome is the correct one.**

Missing `mapString` method just prints the table `char[][]`:

```
private static String mapString(char[][] map) {
    String mapString = "";
    for(int k = 0; k<map.length; k++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<map[k].length; j++) {
            mapString += map[k][j];
        }
        mapString += "\n";
    }
    return mapString;
}
```

While `getMapState` just returns private variable from the `State` class

```
public char[][] getMapState() {
    return map;
}
```

The `Queue` is the type of `Queue<State>` where `State` is my generic type. I can print it by the `toString()` method which results in the second (proper) outcome.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Actual state:\n" + mapString;
}
```

Where the `mapString` is a `String` variable which is initiated in the `State` class constructor with the same exact `String mapString(char[][] map)` method.

```
public State(PlayerAddress player, HashMap<String, BoxAddress> boxList, char[][] map, String solution, String stateHash) {
    this.player = player;
    this.boxList = boxList;
    this.map = map;
    this.solution = solution;
    this.stateHash = stateHash;
    this.boxListString = boxListToString(boxList);
    this.mapString = mapString(map);
}
```

However, later in the code I am not editing the object in the `Queue` but nevertheless it edits itself. What could be the reason? I can provide full code if that would change anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you modifying  ```map``` after passing it to the constructor?

Comment: @JornVernee I am not.

Comment: That was my guess, since you're saving a reference to the array. Doing ```this.map = map.clone()``` instead could still be worth a try.

Comment: Already tried this. It does not help.

Comment: `clone` is only a shallow copy, not a deep copy, so `clone` is not what you want for a `char[][]`. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Probably we need to see more code.  Two points:

1. Where is the method `mapString(char[][] map)` declared?  Your listing shows it as `private static...` so presumably it is inside the State class.  However, your code:

   `System.out.println(mapString(que.element().getMapState()));`
   `System.out.println(que.element());`

appears to indicate that `mapString()` is called from outside the State class as if there were a second version?

2. Try temporarily changing `toString()` to invoke the `mapString()` method and retry.

Other than that, please show all the code.

---

Update:  Thanks for the code.  Having looked at it, my only idea is that Jorn Vernee was on the right track in his earlier response.  Although the constructor in State includes:

`this.map = map.clone();`

this is only a shallow clone and has little effect as the inner level arrays are not cloned.  Could you try a deep clone?  i.e. in the constructor:

```
char[][] newMap = map.clone();
for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
   newMap[i] = map[i].clone();
}
this.map = newMap;
```

Comment: Here is the whole code
[Main class](http://pastebin.com/7ffZqfyQ)
[State class](http://pastebin.com/kRwPDF2E)

Comment: 1. I have it in both. In the Main class it is just for debugging. They are both private so it should not be a problem here. Anyways, they do not change the objects, just print them.
2. Not sure what you meant by that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if you do this `char[][] temp_map = que.element().getMapState()` and then later on you edit the `temp_map` in your code, your first element in the queue changes its value

But honestly, that does not make any sense! Could someone explain that?

Comment: ```temp_map``` is internally a reference, a pointer if you will, to an actual array object in the free store. The thing that is stored in ```que``` is also a pointer. The assignment copies the pointer, but both pointers still point to the same object in the free store.