# How to clear 2d array in java and how to take backup my 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take backup of my 2d array and is there any way how to do this? and how to remove all elements of array ?

```
int arryNumbers[][]= new int[4][5];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can clear array by Loop over the array and and set each element to null.

For String Case:

```
for( int i = 0; i < arryNumbers.length; i++ )
   Arrays.fill( arryNumbers[i], null );
```

For int Case:

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROW.length; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < COL.length; col++) {
      arry[row][col] = 0;
   }
}
```

you take backup by taking (Deep Copy) of your array.

Deep Copy Code:

```
public int[][] copy(int[][] input) {
      int[][] target = new int[input.length][];
      for (int i=0; i <input.length; i++) {
        target[i] = Arrays.copyOf(input[i], input[i].length);
      }
      return target;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `null` in the fill method of an int[] array: `Arrays.fill(int[],int)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a backup : arrayNumbers.clone();

To remove all elements, I guess you should do it yourself with "for" loops statements. (Or set it to null and instantiate it again)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for but does what you ask in probably the fastest way:

```
int[][] newArray = oldArray;
oldArray=new int[4][5];
```

This is the fastest way to achieve what you describe. Note that initializing a new array sets the values to '0' in the case of int or 'null' inthe case of objects.

PS. if old `oldArray` is not symmetric then you can just iterate and initialize each "row" independently.