# Why does my original array gets changed when i only change copied array?

Tags: java, arrays

here i want to make duplicate array "arr" for my tile array and make some changes to it, the problem is when i make the changes (in method neighbors) it applies to the original array "tiles" too

```
public class Board {
    private final int [][] tiles;
    // construct a board from an n-by-n array of blocks
    // (where blocks[i][j] = block in row i, column j)
    public Board(int[][] blocks) {
        tiles = blocks;
    }// all neighboring boards
    public Iterable<Board> neighbors() {
        Queue<Board> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int [][] arr = tiles;
        // do stuff
        if (y+1 < n) {
            int t = arr[x][y];
            arr[x][y] = arr[x][y+1];
            arr[x][y+1] = t;
            Board br = new Board(arr);
            if(!this.equals(br)) {
                q.add(new Board(arr));
            }
        }
        return q;
    } 
}
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: this is not duplicate of pass-by-ref or by-value since the array is not passed as method argument

Comment: when you make this assignment `int [][] arr = tiles;` you do not create a copy of the array, you just point to the same one with a different pointer.  you need to actually create a new array (with the `new ` keyword) and then iterate over the tiles and assign each item to the new array. you can also use `System.arraycopy` see here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Comment: You haven't copied the array, you've only copied a *reference* to the array. Both variables are referring to the same array. See this question to make a deep copy of the array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java

Comment: yup @DavidConrad thanks you got it write..it was driving me crazy i'm kinda new so really thanks if ur comment was answer i would've approved it :)

Comment: also @SharonBenAsher thanks urs is the same

Comment: Very well, seems a little light since it's just referring to another question but I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java arrays are objects. You can use the `clone()` method to copy your array. It will perform a shallow copy - it will work fine with your `int` array.

```
int [][] arr = new int[tiles.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
    arr[i] = tiles[i].clone();
```

1. [copy a 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java)

Comment: still it changes both the arrays

Comment: @AhmadFahmy [Are you sure?](http://ideone.com/Ec01N5) A shallow copy should be enough.

Comment: ops looks like i misunderstood you..your answer is right thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects in Java. [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

And objects are not duplicated in that manner. Your variables "tiles" and "arr" are just pointing at the same array now, you haven't copied it.

To copy an array try System.arraycopy:

```
System.arraycopy( tiles, 0, arr, 0, tiles.length );
```

See more about System copy here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't copied the array, you've only copied a reference to the array. Both variables are referring to the same array. See this question to make a deep copy of the array: [How do I do a deep copy of a 2D array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)