# Object changes unintentionally

Tags: java, object

I'm making a game played on a GameBoard (like 3 in a row).

I save the gameboard in a `int [2]` and like to define the method Move.
In this method, with input which player (1 or 2), row, column and the previous board (Previous), we return a new board (Next).

However, the problem is that after running this method, the object Previous changes with it and this is not my intention. Can someone help me?

```
public class GameBoard {
    public int [] [] board;

    public GameBoard(GameBoard G) {
        this.Board=G.Board;
    }

    public static GameBoard Move(int player,int row, int column, GameBoard Previous) {
        GameBoard Next = new GameBoard(Previous);
        if (player==1) {
        Next.setBoard(row,column,-1); ();}
        if (player==2) {
        Next.setBoard(row,column,1);}
        return Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.Board=G.Board;` doesn't copy the array.

Comment: AndyTurner beat me to the likely reason; have a look here for what you possibly want to do instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions, variable names, fields and parmeters should start with a lowercase letter, so `g` (not `G`), `previous` (not `Previous`), `board` (not `Board`), `next` (not `Next`). Similarly, your `if`-formatting is rather odd. People take these conventions as visual hints, and not following them makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java