# Java: Is int[][] a primitive type? Or does it generate a different instance with clone() method?

Tags: java, int, clone, primitive-types

I'm working with an int[n][n] board:

```
0 2 3 
4 1 5 
7 8 6
```

I want to make a copy called twin, then return the modified copy.

For example:

```
    int [][] twin = board.clone();

    twin[0][0] = board[0][1];
    twin[0][1] = board[0][0];

    return twin;
```

What I expected is:

```
//board
0 2 3 
4 1 5 
7 8 6 

//twin
2 0 3 
4 1 5 
7 8 6
```

But the result is:

```
//board
2 2 3 
4 1 5 
7 8 6 

//twin
2 2 3 
4 1 5 
7 8 6
```

The board and twin were the same all along and the clone was not working as expected. Is it because int[][] is not an object?

Is there a way to clone int[][] and modify the way I was expecting? Should I loop over board and copy the values to twin?

Comment: Hey take a gander at how to clone a 2d array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, an array is not a primitive type; it's an object.  Second, multidimensional arrays are implemented as arrays of arrays.  Also, the `clone` method for arrays is shallow.  When you `clone` a multi-dimensional array, your new multidimensional array still refers back to the original internal arrays.

```
board -> [ .           .           . ]
           |           |           |
           v           v           v
          [0, 2, 3], [4, 1, 5], [7, 8, 6]
           ^           ^           ^
           |           |           |
 twin -> [ .           .           . ]
```

So when you modify the values, you're not copying from two different arrays, you're copying from the same array, which is why you wind up with [2, 2, 3].

If you're going to clone a multidimensional array, you'll need to clone all the way down to the one-dimensional arrays also.

```
int [][] twin = board.clone();
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    twin[i] = board[i].clone();
}
```

Now I get `[[2, 0, 3], [4, 1, 5], [7, 8, 6]]`.

Other possibilities include declaring your new multidimensional array without cloning, and using loops and `System.arraycopy` to copy individual one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting JLS [Chapter 10. Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects

No `int[][]` is not a primitive.

---

Quoting JLS [10.7. Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.

The outer array is a new instance, the subarrays are not.